# most of it can be attributed to extractive industries

Tags: modal-verbs

“In addition, the Ebola outbreak in Guinea, Liberia and Sierra Leone has increased food inflation in the three countries and the subregion, threatening to push many people below the minimum level of dietary energy consumption,” it said.

Although gross domestic product has remained positive since 2001, and above the global average, *most of it **can** be attributed to extractive industries, including minerals, oil and gas*. This has not created enough jobs, especially for young people. (https://www.theguardian.com/global-development/2015/sep/28/united-nations-hails-impressive-mdg-gains-on-education-reducing-child-mortality-africa)

Q1) Can I paraphrase the italicized part in either of the following two ways

a) It **will be reasonable** to attribute most of it to extractive industries...

b) It **is reasonable** to attribute most of it to extractive industries...

Q2) Can I replace the "can" in the original sentence with "could"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could modify the statement with "is reasonable to attribute", but you would be weakening it and making it more verbose at the same time. The phrase "will be reasonable" is even worse in that respect.

The same argument applies to substituting "could" for "can". Where "could" might fit would be in a conditional statement like this:

> ... most of it **could** be attributed to extractive industries, **if** there were no other reasons.

Comment: Can we think of the "can" sentence in a similar way: *... most of it **can** be attributed to extractive industries, **if** there are no other reasons*?

Comment: That could be used if the matter is to be considered later. The verb "can" in the original quote has the sense of something already determined- "Can it be attributed to these industries?"..."Yes, it can."

Comment: That's what I wanted to know! And that's why I gave two paraphrases: "it **will be** reasonable" and "it **is** reasonable". I thought "can" in the original quote suggested both of these meanings: (a) "already determined" sense and (b) "future consideration" sense. But I was wrong. Am I right? .... I think with interpretation (b) above, people would use "can" and "could" interchangeably. Am I right?

Comment: As I read it, the original with 'can' is not ambiguous; the paragraph goes on to mention consequences of the attribution.